# Возможности триггеров в WPF

Tags: wpf, триггер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли с помощью триггеров в WPF задавать сложные условия, в том числе и не одно?
Например, отобразить элемент#3 если виден элемент #1 или элемент#2 (свойство Visibility). Пусть в качестве элементов выступают textbox'ы, textblock'и и тому подобные.
Или отобразить элемент если выбранное значение combobox равно "некоторому значению"?
Если не сложно приведите пожалуйста примеры. Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Добавьте соответствующую метку к вопросу о языке разработки, чтобы внести ясность в вопрос.

Comment: @DenisBubnov а зачем? Вопрос не связан с каким-нибудь конкретным языком программирования

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть несколько различных вариантов использования триггеров со сложными условиями.

Один случай, когда нужно получить результат логического И между несколькими условиями (условие1 и условие2 и т.д.). Для этого существуют специальные версии триггеров `MultiTrigger` и `MultiDataTrigger`. Первый используется для биндинга к свойствам элемента управления, второй для биндинга к элементам данных в `DataContext` (но не только).

Пример, третий элемент будет виден, только если видны первые два:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Element1"
                   Text="1" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="Element2"
                   Text="2" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="Element3"
                   Text="3"
                   Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=Element1}"
                           Value="Visible" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=Element2}"
                           Value="Visible" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="Element3"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />           
         </MultiDataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Как видно, `MultiDataTrigger` позволяет биндиться и к свойствам элементов управления, если в биндинге задать свойство `ElementName`. Также много магии можно сделать через использование `RelativeSource`.

Другой случай - это любое другое сложное условие, не только логическое И. В таком случае можно использовать обычные `Trigger` или `DataTrigger` с применением `MultiBinding` и конвертера, который реализует `IMultiValueConverter`, внутри которого и реализуется вычисление нужного нам сложного логического условия от переданных параметров.

Пример, аналогичный предыдущему, только теперь у нас условие ИЛИ между видимостью первых двух элементов и И для выбранного `CheckBox`.

Конвертер:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Converters
{
    public class TestConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Length == 3)
            {
                var vis1 = values[0] as Visibility?;
                var vis2 = values[1] as Visibility?;
                var vis3 = values[2] as bool?;
                if (vis1 != null && vis2 != null && vis3 != null)
                {
                    return vis3.Value && (vis1.Value == Visibility.Visible
                        || vis2.Value == Visibility.Visible);
                }
            }
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("TestConverter может быть использован только в режиме OneWay.");
        }
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
    <Window x:Class="Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Converters"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <conv:TestConverter x:Key="TestConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="Element1"
                           Text="1" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="Element2"
                           Text="2" />
                <CheckBox x:Name="Element3"
                          Content="3" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="Element4"
                           Text="4"
                           Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TestConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Visibility"
                                     ElementName="Element1" />
                            <Binding Path="Visibility"
                                     ElementName="Element2" />
                            <Binding Path="IsChecked"
                                     ElementName="Element3" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter TargetName="Element4"
                            Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.ContentTemplate>
</Window>
```

Бонусом случай с отображением элемента при определённом выбранном значении в `ComboBox`, хоть это и не сложное условие:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox">
            <sys:String>Element1</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Element2</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Element3</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Element4, TextBlock is visible</sys:String>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock"
                   Text="Text"
                   Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ComboBox}"
                     Value="Element4, TextBlock is visible">
            <Setter TargetName="TextBlock"
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

В реальном приложении, однако, в `SelectedItem` у `ComboBox` будет лежать скорей всего не строка, а какой-то объект и такой триггер написать не получится, но это решается либо через задание `SelectedValue` у `ComboBox`, либо через конвертер, который будет проверять объект на равенство чему-то и возвращать `bool`. А вообще это не нужно делать через триггеры, это нужно делать через свойства модели представления.

Comment: Логическое ИЛИ можно по идее получить проще, просто использовать _два_ отдельных триггера.

Comment: @VladD, да, вы правы, это будет работать, но это просто пример. Если выражение более сложное, чем просто или, то удобнее использовать конвертер. К слову говоря, конвертеры значительно быстрее множества триггеров.

Comment: Это я к тому, что, возможно, стоит поменять мотивирующий пример для конвертеров на более сложный. Ведь ИЛИ можно получить и без конвертера.

Comment: @VladD, сделано.